# How to store variables to disk so you can use them next time the PowerShell script runs?

Tags: powershell, variables

I would like to store a variable to disk or registry so I can use it the next time I run the scheduled script? Preferably an one-liner or two...

Cheers,
Roy

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$foo | Export-CliXml foo.xml
```

then later

```
$foo = Import-CliXml foo.xml
```

Note that if $foo represents a live object, when you restore it, you are only going to get its properties. However the type information is more-or-less preserved.  For example if you save out a System.Diagnostics.Process object, when you rehydrate it you will have a Deserialzed.System.Diagnostics.Process object.

BTW if you need to store/retrieve multiple variables, you can do that like so:

```
Get-Variable bla* | Export-Clixml vars.xml
Import-Clixml .\vars.xml | %{ Set-Variable $_.Name $_.Value }
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm ;) Only needed to store one integer... Tnx!

Comment: If you don't need full type information, other options are Get-Content/Set-Content and Import-CSV/Export-CSV.